# AlaSQL update Javascript object Where certain conditions are met

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alasql

I'm trying to learn how to use AlaSQL and want to perform an update command on an array of objects, this is what I was trying to do:

```
alasql('UPDATE ? SET cc_fee=? WHERE id=?', [$scope.payments, response.cc_fee, response.id]);
```

That returns a parsing error that it was expecting a literal rather then an expression.

I also tried this:

```
alasql('UPDATE $scope.payments SET cc_fee=? WHERE id=?', [response.cc_fee, response.id]);
```

That didn't create any errors, but it didn't alter the object at all.

`$scope.payments` is a simple array of objects.

Any ideas on the correct way to do this?

Comment: You cant update an object. You can only make a copy into a table, update the table and select * into the object

Comment: I didn't understand. Can give me a example, please??